# how to check a remote udp port

Tags: c#, udpclient

I want to check the connection to a remote machine using UDPClient. Heard that it will return an icmp packet if failure occurs. How we can catch it?
 How it is possible to check for a remote machine?

```
            UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient();
            receivingUdpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.2.2.13"), 80);

            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0");
            Var b=receivingUdpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
```

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118113/c-sockets-send-udp-and-process-icmp-reply-from-router so you can see the answers there. By the way, ICMP may be repressed by the other side so you may not receive it at all. Check with Wireshark or similar first.

Answer (score 0):

With UDP, there is no definite way of knowing whether the packet reached its destination or not (compare with TCP, which sends ack packets to let the sender know its packet was received).

It is true that in some cases, [ICMP packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Destination_unreachable) are sent, but what if the packet was filtered out (or simply dropped) somewhere along the routing path? As far as I have seen, most home routers are pre-configured to drop all ICMP on external ports, for example.

Instead of relying on ICMP packets, you could investigate if the protocol you are using has a PING packet (or some equivalent no-op packet, or if you created the protocol -- add it!) and use that with a timeout/retry logic to verify if the service is available.