# ICMP errors are not returned to connected UDP socket?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking, icmp

RFC 1122 *Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers* indicates in [section 3.2.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-40)

> 

```
        An incoming Time Exceeded message MUST be passed to the
        transport layer.
```

and also (section 3.2.2)

> ```
>     In those cases where the Internet layer is required to pass an
> ```

```
     ICMP error message to the transport layer, the IP protocol
     number MUST be extracted from the original header and used to
     select the appropriate transport protocol entity to handle the
     error.
```

To me this means that any UNIX must pass these messages to the transport layer (I say UNIX, because I am concerned with UNIX network programming and was originally wondering if it maybe varied by UNIX flavor). In other words, it is portable and I don't need to use Linux `IP_RECVERR` and `recvmsg()`.

However, [this IETF thread](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/behave/current/msg10927.html) indicates that in the case of UDP transport, ICMP error messages are only propagated in the case of *connected* UDP sockets.

**On Mac OS X I've written a little program (code below) that uses a connected UDP socket, sends a packet with a short TTL, but does not receive the ICMP Time Exceeded message. What gives?**

edit: I've also tests on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the same issue.

I used Wireshark to verify the ICMP message is, in fact, being received by my computer.

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <err.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    #define MAXDATASIZE 1500

    /**
     * Prints a formatted message to stderr, prints a friendly version of errno, and then exits with error code 1.
     */
    void errorf(char *fmt, ...) {
      va_list args;
      va_start(args, fmt);
      vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
      va_end(args);
      perror(NULL);
      exit(1);
    }

    // get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
    void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
    {
      if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
      }

      return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int sockfd, numbytes;
        char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        int rv;
        char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        int ttl;

        if (argc != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

        if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
            return 1;
        }

        // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
        for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
            if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                    p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
                continue;
            }
            printf("got a socket\n");

            if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                close(sockfd);
                continue;
            }
            printf("connected\n");

            break;
        }

        if (p == NULL) {
            errorf("client: failed to connect\n");
        }

        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
                s, sizeof s);
        printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

        freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

        ttl = 1;
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl)) == -1) {
          errorf("can't set unicast time-to-live");
        }
        if ((numbytes = send(sockfd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0)) == -1) {
          errorf("send");
        } else {
          printf("send : %d\n", numbytes);
        }

        printf("receiving\n");
        // I expect this to fail if send() resulted in an ICMP error message
        // but instead it hangs.
        if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
            errorf("recv");
        }

        close(sockfd);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In `errorf()` you need to save and restore `errno` around the call to `vprintf()`. Otherwise, it might change `errno`, and `perror()` will print the wrong message.

Comment: Try setting TTL a little higher, like 3 or 4. `1` might be too small, so it never gets to a router that sends TTL Exceeded.

Comment: Try downloading the source to `traceroute` and compare what you're doing.

Comment: 1. That shouldn't change the behaviour of recv. It also never gets called between send() and recv() since I'm _not_ seeing errors.
2. As I mentioned in the question, I am seeing an ICMP TTL Exceeded message from my router in Wireshark.
3. `traceroute` doesn't use connected UDP sockets, it uses a raw ICMP to receive errors (this is fine, but not what I'm testing)

Comment: "_3. traceroute doesn't use connected UDP sockets, it uses a raw ICMP to receive errors (this is fine, but not what I'm testing)_" UDP doesn't have connections, and whether or not it uses UDP depends on the implementation. Many implementations of traceroute _do_ use UDP.

Comment: UDP doesn't have connections in the same sense that TCP does, but there is still the concept of _connected_ UDP sockets. Search for them and you will find them in manpages, RFCs, and Richard's *UNIX Network Programming*.

traceroute does _not_ use connected UDP sockets. It uses raw ICMP to _receive_ packets and a variety of protocols to _send_ packets (sometimes UDP).

Comment: Where in _[RFC 768, User Datagram Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc768)_, the definition of UDP, do you even find the word connection? Your claim that it is part of the RFCs is simply not true. It simply isn't there because UDP is connectionless. Your idea of a UDP connection is an application-layer connection, and _not_ part of UDP. On the other hand, TCP creates connections.

Comment: In fact, look at _[RFC 5405, Unicast UDP Usage Guidelines for Application Designers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5405)_: "_The User Datagram Protocol (UDP) provides a minimal, unreliable, best-effort, message-passing transport to applications and upper-layer protocols (both simply called "applications" in the remainder of this document). Compared to other transport protocols, UDP and its UDP-Lite variant are unique in that they do not establish end-to-end connections between communicating end systems._"

Comment: Yes, UDP is connectionless (like I said above). However, the _concept_ of a connected UDP socket is provided by the kernel. In other words, you can `connect()` a UDP socket and the kernel will maintain a bit of state for you (eg. you can `send()` and `recv()` rather than `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`). Now, this _doesn't_ change the protocol, but it is still relevant to my question because it (apparently) changes when the kernel passes ICMP error messages to the transport layer. If you have any advice on that implementation I'm all ears.

Comment: Really, before telling me what the RFCs say, you should take the time to read them. "_Many operating systems also allow a UDP socket to be connected, i.e., to bind a UDP socket to a specific pair of addresses and ports. This is similar to the corresponding TCP sockets API functionality. However, for UDP, **this is only a local operation** that serves to simplify the local send/receive functions and to filter the traffic for the specified addresses and ports. **Binding a UDP socket does not establish a connection**_"

Comment: The RFC also give you a key: "_On some stacks, a bound socket also allows an application to be notified when ICMP error messages are received for its transmissions [RFC1122]._"

Comment: Ok, I think we are talking past each other. As you've pointed out BCP145 discusses connected UDP sockets as a local operation.

What section of RFC1122 is your following from? (ctrl-f doesn't pick it up).

Comment: That is part of RFC 5405. The RFCs reference previous RFCs. RFC 5405 is referencing the host requirements of IP laid out in RFC 1122.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. RFC 1122 section 4.1.3.3 *UDP MUST pass to the application layer all ICMP error messages that it receives from the IP layer.* Still confused as to why my application's socket is not receiving the TTL exceeded message.

Comment: Something like this is indeed supposed to work, see [Socket FAQ](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-5.html) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118113/c-sockets-send-udp-and-process-icmp-reply-from-router?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I tried adding `sleep(1)` before `recv()` in case it's timing, but it still fails. Maybe it isn't reported as an error and there's some other way to get it.